# Random crash while retrieving the lat/long using worklight 6.2 Android acquireGeoPosition API

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

My Android app tries to retrieve the current location of the device using the Worklight Android API acquireGeoPosition.

The geo policy details are as mentioned below -

```
    WLGeoAcquisitionPolicy geoPolicy = WLGeoAcquisitionPolicy.getLiveTrackingProfile();
    geoPolicy.setTimeout(60000); 
    geoPolicy.setMaximumAge(15000);
```

Couple of times, I have noticed app crashing with the below stacktrace that says 'altitude must be non-negative, was -500.0'. Any clues on what could have triggered this crash pls...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-361

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: altitude must be non-negative, was -500.0
    at com.worklight.location.api.geo.WLCoordinate.<init>(WLCoordinate.java:73)
    at com.worklight.location.internal.geo.nativeImpl.AndroidLocationListener.convertToPosition(AndroidLocationListener.java:145)
    at com.worklight.location.internal.geo.nativeImpl.AndroidLocationListener.onLocationChanged(AndroidLocationListener.java:140)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:268)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:201)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$2.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at com.worklight.location.internal.nativeImpl.AndroidRunnableExecutor$1.run(AndroidRunnableExecutor.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: This looks like a defect that should be fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been identified as a possible defect.

To have it investigated as well as receive a fix, you need to have the customer [open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) for IBM so that an iFix could be provided, once available.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check with the concerned to raise an SR.